# selenium cannot find element with class in IE

Tags: xpath, selenium, cucumber, css-selectors, webrat

I'm using selenium_client with cucumber, webrat + IE
As you'd expect, Firefox works fine. I've tried the following:

```
selenium.is_visible("css=#flash .flash_notice")
selenium.is_visible("xpath=//*[@id='flash']/*[@class='flash_notice]")
selenium.is_visible("xpath=//*[@id='flash']/*[contains(@class,'flash_notice]')")
```

both cannot find the element.
I think it must be something to do with IE, looking closer at the html selenium returns from IE...
It looks like this:

```
<UL id=flash>
  <LI className=flash_notice>Deleted</LI>
</UL>
```

Notice IE returns the class attribute as className, is this confusing selenium? How can I get round this so that I can use the same statement for selenium using IE and Firefox

Just to confuse us even more, this example works, confirming its something to do with checking the class attribute

```
selenium.is_visible("xpath=//*[@id='flash']/*[. =\'Deleted\']")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It appears that your XPATH expressions are mal-formed.**

The first XPATH is missing the single quote `'` at the end of `flash_notice`.

**It should be:**

`selenium.is_visible("xpath=//*[@id='flash']/*[@class='flash_notice']")`

The second XPATH has the `'` `]` and `)` out of order, which messes up the expression.

**It should be:**

`selenium.is_visible("xpath=//*[@id='flash']/*[contains(@class,'flash_notice')]")`